# Prove using the ε-δ definition that f(x) is continuous at the following points?

Tags: analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

How can I use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition to do this for 
$f(x) = \frac{x + 2}{x^2 + x + 1}$ at $x=1$
and for 
$f(x) = \log(x^2 + 1)$ at $x=0$? I can do it for a normal function but I get confused when it gets to the stage of $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ and I have to restrict this in terms of $|x-0|<\delta$ or $|x-1|<\delta$. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that by normal function you mean a polynomial. In the cases you've given, the problems work very similarly, but it is often less clear what choices to make for $\delta$.

To begin, fix $\epsilon>0$. At some point, we will need a $\delta$, but we don't know what it should be yet, so we'll just assume it is greater than 0. Suppose we have $|x-1|<\delta$. Then \begin{align}
|f(x)-f(1)|&=\left|\frac{x+2}{x^2+x+1}-\frac{1+2}{1^2+1+1}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{x+2}{x^2+x+1}-1\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{1-x^2}{x^2+x+1}\right|\\
&=\frac{|1-x||1+x|}{|x^2+x+1|}\\
&\leq\frac{\delta|x+1|}{|x^2+x+1|}
\end{align}

At this point, we can determine what we want $\delta$ to be. Setting $\delta=\min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{3}\}$ is enough in this case, see if you can figure out how to go from there.

Comment: let δ≤1 and then |x-1|<1 --> x<2

following from the last line: δ|x+1|/|x^2+x+1| < 3δ/7 --> δ = 7ε/3

but i don't see how you got the ε/2 above

Comment: You want to continue with inequalities, so you want something that is bigger than the last term. You can accomplish that by increasing the numerator or decreasing the denominator. I actually made an error with my choice of $\delta$, but you have the right idea using $x<2$.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for your help, really do appreciate it...been searching all over the place :)

Answer (score 0):

For the second function, recalling that $f(0)=0$ and that $f(x) \geq 0$ since $1+x^2\geq 1$, you pick $\varepsilon>0$ and start with the inequality
$$
|f(x)-f(0)| <\varepsilon,
$$
namely
$$
\log(1+x^2)<\varepsilon.
$$
Since log is a strictly increasing function, your last inequality is equivalent to
$$
1+x^2 < e^\varepsilon.
$$
Hence
$$
-\sqrt{e^\varepsilon-1} < x < \sqrt{e^\varepsilon-1},
$$
and you can define $\delta=\sqrt{e^\varepsilon-1}>0$.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, i finally get it...i forgot about taking exponentials of both sides